# passing Collection of abstract class as parameter in function

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pass `ICollection<AbstractClass>` in function as parameter. But when I call it with Collection of concrete types Visual Studio show me error that

> method has some invalid arguments

My function is :

```
    private void GenerateId(ICollection<BaseEntity> entities)
    {
        foreach (BaseEntity e in entities)
        {
           e.Id = _baseDao.GetNextId();
        }
    }
```

My call is :

```
GenerateId(entity.TitleAdmRegions);
```

Type of AdmRegions:

```
public virtual ICollection<TitleAdmRegion> TitleAdmRegions { get; set; }
```

And AdmRegion is:

```
public partial class TitleAdmRegion : BaseEntity
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do an explicit cast - in fact, there's no guarantee that a collection of `T`, where `T` inherits from `U` is also a collection of `U`. Of course, it most likely will be, but...

The relation is called covariance - the ability to use a more specific type in generic "call" instead of its ancestor. MSDN has a nice article on the topic in C# - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The type-safe way is actually quite simple using generics:

```
private void GenerateId<T>(ICollection<T> entities)
  where T: BaseEntity
{
    foreach (var e in entities)
    {
       e.Id = _baseDao.GetNextId();
    }
}
```

Also, while `ICollection<T>` is not covariant, `IEnumerable<T>` is. So another simple way would be to use `IEnumerable<BaseEntity>` as the parameter:

```
private void GenerateId<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) { ... }
```

Comment: Luaan, Thanks a lot! It works with Generics(1st ur example) and it works with IEnumerable.

Comment: This link explains about covariant types: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The interface `ICollection<T>` is not covariant in `T`. It couldn't be because the type contains methods such as `void Add(T item)`. We have that

> a `TitleAdmRegion` is a `BaseEntity`

but without covariance, that does ***not*** imply that

> an `ICollection<TitleAdmRegion>` is an `ICollection<BaseEntity>`

as you seem to think. The solution is to switch to an interface that is covariant in its type argument. You can use either `IEnumerable<out T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`. Covariance means that an `IEnumerable<TitleAdmRegion>` is an `IEnumerable<BaseEntity>`, and an `IReadOnlyCollection<TitleAdmRegion>` is an `IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEntity>`. So change the signature to:

```
private void GenerateId(IEnumerable<BaseEntity> entities) // or IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEntity>, or IReadOnlyList<BaseEntity>, etc.
{
    foreach (BaseEntity e in entities)
    {
       e.Id = _baseDao.GetNextId();
    }
}
```

and all will be fine.

Covariance (and contravariance) in generics was new in .NET 4.0 (2010). The interface `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>` was new in .NET 4.5 (2012). Note that collections that allow both reading and writing (such as the `List<T>` class and the `T[]` array type) do implement `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`.